# Job jenkins gives error 137 and fails after ng build --aot from angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, jenkins, cypress

Being trying to automatize the run of the e2e tests from my angular app in jenkins.
The tests are handled thanks to the Cypress framework.
The problem is that the jenkins job fails before the tests are even called, so my guess is that there is something wrong with my angular config.

When I run the same instructions from jenkins locally, I am able to build my app, and run my tests without any problem.

I found a possible solution which is changing the `target": "es2015",` to `es5`, but after doing that, I got lots of errors.

Here's the some of the output message in jenkins:

```
15:26:35 Run `npm audit` for details.
15:26:35 npm run build
15:26:35 
15:26:35 > my-app@0.0.1 build
15:26:35 > ng build --aot
15:26:35
15:26:35 Warning: Support was requested for IE 11 in the project's browserslist configuration. IE 11 support is deprecated since Angular v12.
15:26:35 For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
15:26:35 - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
15:29:26 ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
15:29:26 ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
15:29:26 - Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
15:29:26 /tmp/build-ccb28c3f.sh: line 1: 71574 Killed                  ng build --aot
15:29:26 make[1]: *** [Makefile:535: webapp] Error 137
```

and here, my angular version:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/

Angular CLI: 12.2.17
Node: 14.20.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.17
OS: linux x64

Angular: 12.2.16
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.17
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.17
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.17
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.17
@angular/cdk                    12.2.13
@angular/cli                    12.2.17
@schematics/angular             12.2.17
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```

And here's my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./webapp",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "target": "es2015",
    "paths": {
      "jszip": [
        "node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"
      ]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      { "name": "typescript-tslint-plugin"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Node  v16.16.0 & npm 8.11.0 in the machine which runs the jenkins job

Comment: Hello, I updated my npm & node, and tried to generate the app locally with the same versions of npm & node as the ones from the jenkins job, but everything just worked fine.
The error is still been generated from the jenkins job